# Angular 4 Lazy Loading

Tags: node.js, angular, lazy-loading

I'm trying to understand this so if somebody could please explain it to me, I'd appreciate it very much.

My understanding is that we cannot do lazy loading in angular without node.js. Is that true? If not, could you please point me to the spot where I can learn about how to do it without node.js?

Please and thanks.

Comment: Have you really googled ?

Comment: https://namitamalik.github.io/Lazy-Loading-with-Angular2-Routing/

Comment: There is a million articles about that, wtf

Comment: No need to be a "smart guy". Of course I searched. I even had it implemented and working at one point, but on my dev machine only. As soon as I published it to my hosting site (without node.js), the app stopped working all together. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true. While both anchored in Javascript, Angular and Node.js are two separate technologies, with two separate concerns. Node.js is a backend architecture built to process and deliver data, while Angular is a frontend technology primarily concerned with providing users a gateway to interact with the services providing the data through a GUI.

In Angular lazy loading modules is done through the router [as documented here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router). Essentially you don't import the module you want to lazy load until the route to that module has been activated, for example:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' },
    { path: 'heroes', loadChildren: 'app/hero/hero.module#HeroModule' }
];
```

Be careful, and read the Angular documentation carefully as there are quite a few "gotchas" with Lazy Loading. A few I can think of:

1. You only need to load the module in the route. Trying to import it into your parent module will negate the "laziness" of the module and in some cases cause errors.
2. Lazy loaded modules cause the Dependency Injection tree to be split. In other words, if you call the same service in the parent module and the child module, they'll be in separate contexts, so they won't necessarily be aware of one another unless you declare the service as [forRoot(), more on that here.](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-modules-di.html)

Overall it's fairly simple to do though. Just follow the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm all aware of it. At one point I had it implement  and it worked fine. The reason why I thought it would not work without the node.js is, it worked all fine on my dev machine, but as soon as I published it to my hosting site (that does not have node.js), the application stopped working all together. Am I missing something that I need to dow when I publish the app?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion You need to build Your angular app using angular-cli: `ng build --prod --env=prod`
Then in `src` folder angular-cli would generate `dist` folder in this folder Your application ready to upload to the server.